# Use list comprehension to build a tuple

Tags: python

How can I use list comprehension to build a tuple of 2-tuple from a list. It would be equivalent to

```
tup = ()
for element in alist:
    tup = tup + ((element.foo, element.bar),)
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
tup = tuple((element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist)
```

Technically, it's a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). It's like a list comprehension, but it's evaluated lazily and won't need to allocate memory for an intermediate list.

For completeness, the list comprehension would look like this:

```
tup = tuple([(element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist])
```

PS: `attrgetter` is not faster (`alist` has a million items here):

```
In [37]: %timeit tuple([(element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist])
1 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

In [38]: %timeit tuple((element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist)
10 loops, best of 3: 155 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit tuple(map(operator.attrgetter('foo','bar'), alist))
1 loops, best of 3: 283 ms per loop

In [40]: getter = operator.attrgetter('foo','bar')

In [41]: %timeit tuple(map(getter, alist))
1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop

In [46]: %timeit tuple(imap(getter, alist))
1 loops, best of 3: 264 ms per loop
```

Comment: you could also do `tuple(map(operator.attrgetter('foo','bar'),alist))`.  I would probably use the one you posted for readability, but `attrgetter` might have a slight performance advantage.  You'd have to `timeit` and see if this is in a real tight loop.

Comment: What is the difference between a list comprehension and generator expression in this example since tuple() is called on it?  Wouldn't it consume the same memory footprint regardless of the form?

Comment: @mgilson: I tested it and it's twice as slow with or without a cached getter.

Comment: @EricRoper: list comprehension will create a whole new list and then pass it to the tuple constructor.

Comment: Passing the generator expression to the tuple constructor has the effect of evaluating the whole generator expression and uses the same memory as the list comprehension.  The list comprehension runs about 20% faster on my machine.  I can see the benefit of a generator if using the terms one by one but don't see any advantage when passing to the tuple constructor.

Comment: @EricRoper No, it uses the double of the memory. First it consumes all the elements of the generator to build a list, and **then** a tuple is created from the list. At that point there are two copies of the "set" of elements yielded by the generator, and only after some time the list is garbage collected. If the generator is huge you may not be able to keep both the list and tuple in memory at the same time, even for an instruction.
The slowdown of attrgetter is expected, since you are replacing an attribute lookup with a function call plus attribute lookup.

Comment: The version with the list is almost twice as fast as the version without, though.  Why is that?  Are you sure it uses less memory?

Comment: _`tup = tuple((el... ) for el in alist)` Technically, it's a generator expression..._   
**This is misleading as it suggests that `tup` would be a generator expression, which is not the case, `tup` is a tuple!** `((el... ) for el in alist)` would be a generator expression.

Comment: @Bakuriu it's not clear that the tuple-of-generatorExpression doesn't also build an intermediate data structure under-the-covers.  It has to create all of the elements of the generator and put them *somewhere*... does it put them directly into the tuple?  Maybe, but tuples are immutable, so I harbor some doubt about that.  Probably this is implementation-dependent, and CPython might even behave differently w.r.t. memory footprint than other flavours.

Comment: @Him The fact that tuples are immutable doesn't say anything about how the manage memory *on initialization*. Immutability means **once the object is created** it doesn't change. For the case of tuples, the constructor will receive the generator. The generator provides no size hint and thus it will allocate some memory and start consuming it, when the memory is not enough it will call `resize` and the memory block allocated will increase/possibly being moved. This is repeated. The increment in memory allocation follows the usual methods to avoid quadratic slow downs.

Comment: @Bakuriu This looks to be true for CPython. [Is this the code that you're referencing](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6fd4c8ec7740523bb81191c013118d9d6959bc9d/Objects/abstract.c#L2031)?

Comment: @Him I'm pretty sure that the language specifies that `tuple(iterable)` must take O(n) memory and O(n) time. Certainly no Python implementation makes `tuple(iterable)` take O(n^2) time due to reallocation policies and I don't think any Python implementation would do as you suggest, i.e. creating a different allocation pool and then move the elements into the tuple.. it simply doesn't make sense. The OS takes care of increasing the allocation size inplace if it can or it moves the data in a place where a bigger free memory slot is available

Comment: @Bakuriu OMG surely it wouldn't take O(n^2)!  Reallocating the memory exactly 50 times upon tuple creation is still O(n).  :)  "The OS takes care of it."  I mean, kind of.  Did you look at the link I posted?  It looks like the CPython programmers use a standard memory realloc to grow the space.  Realloc may or may not memcpy the whole current contents of the array, depending on the current situation in memory.  Probably do a similar thing when casting a generator to list.

Comment: @Him It will take O(n^2) if you don't use the correct reallocation strategy. For example if you just allocate 10 new slots every time you fill the memory then it's going to take O(n^2) time. To avoid the quadratic blowup Python (and any other language) will instead "double" the memory reserved each time they fill the memory allocated.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the already working answer:

```py
tup = tuple((element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist)
```

**The shortest way is** (comma at end is mandatory!):

```py
tup = *((elements.foo, elements.bar) for elements in alist),
```

It' s arguable which solution is the more readable or more pythonic.

[Explanation of:](https://www.pythonpool.com/tuple-comprehension/#:%7E:text=A%20tuple%20comprehension%20is%20considered,tuple%20around%20a%20generator%20object.) `*(...),`

Answer (score -2):

You may use the following expression

```
tup = *[(element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist]
```

This will first of all generate a list of tuples and then it will convert that list of tuples into a tuple of tuples.

Comment: you forgot to add trailing comma. With out it you will get an error  `tup = *[(element.foo, element.bar) for element in alist],`

Comment: Using a list in between is IMAHO not very good. It works without the list if you add a comma in the end as @RomanKazakov mentioned